# how to define global variable in VB.NET?

Tags: variables, initialization, global, declare

how to declare global variable in VB.NET (Web Forms "ASPX")  and use this variable in all pages ?
how is Method Initialize and Cancel initialized in web page ?
Thank you

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

You must declare static variables,... you find your answer step by step in below link:

[global-variables-aspnet](http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variables-aspnet)